# make linking static libc not dynamic

Tags: opencv, build, cmake, makefile, dynamic-linking

I am trying to build an open source library (openCV in this case) from source using cmake and make. However, I run into a linking error

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libc.a(lib_a-mallocr.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `__malloc_av_' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libc.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

From what I gather, this means make is using the static version of glibc libc.a instead of the dynamic lib.so.6. I'm assuming I need to change a path somewhere in cmake but I'm unsure of where to look. Any help is appreciated.

edit: I'm doing this on a 64 bit linux mint machine

Comment: Nothing mint distributed should be in `/usr/local` so that's something either you put there or that the build put there. What is it? That error tells you exactly the flag you need to add to the build process to fix things (but it needs to be added to the build of all the pieces).

Comment: libc.a is the GNU C library. According to the gnu website that's the standard place it's installed and I installed it using apt-get install build-essential so I'm pretty sure that's where it's supposed to be.

Comment: There is a version of it, libc.so.6 that is supposed to be linked to by dynamic libraries but for some reason make isn't using it.
libc.so.6 is located in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu btw

Comment: No system packages install anything to `/usr/local`. That's not what they do. You can check that. What does `dpkg -S /usr/local/lib/libc.a` output? `/lib` **is** a system package location.

Comment: I did not know about the -S flag, that's a handy thing. At some point I must have thought it was a good idea to build the c standard library and stick it in `/usr/local`. Don't know what fit of madness possessed me to try that. Removing the libraries solved the problem. Thanks for the help @Etan